# nopcommerce 3.5 generic url engine

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm looking for the engine root implementation of nopcommerce 3.50 and there is something mysterious for me.
In the Nop.Web project , the "Infrastructure" directory contains GenericUrlRouteProvider class who registers root for generic urls.
This class is a mistery for me because i don't understand how nopcommerce do the difference between urls.

I take one example :

--> if you write this url in your browser : http://localhost:15536/books   -->it retdirect to the "book" category  dispaying books.

--> if you write this url in your browser : http://localhost:15536/cooking-for-two -->it redirect the product page of the item "cooking-for-two"

this is 2 diifferens contents and pages but this is exactly the same root definition :

```
        routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Product",
                                 "{SeName}",
                                 new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetails" },
                                 new[] {"Nop.Web.Controllers"});

        routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Category",
                        "{SeName}",
                        new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category" },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

My question is how nopcommerce determine which root to execute (action and controller) when you call http://localhost:15536/books or http://localhost:15536/cooking-for-two... ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have database access you would see there is a table '[dbo].[UrlRecord]'

Do following query

```
SELECT  [Id]
      ,[EntityId]
      ,[EntityName]
      ,[Slug]
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[LanguageId]
  FROM [dbo].[UrlRecord]
```

Query result.

Examples: 
1) Slug : cooking-for-two , EntityName : Product and EntityId : 22 ,

2) Slug : books, EntityName : Category, EntityId : 1

Based on the EntityName and EntityId system route to corresponding controller action and id

For more details read : http://www.pronopcommerce.com/nopcommerce-id-less-url-structure-demystified-how-does-nopcommerce-270-and-280-resolve-urls